# Why is Monday such a bad day for questions?

Tags: discussion

I guess everybody is aware of the type of questions we get on Mondays. Why's that?

There must be some serious (scientifically founded) explanation to that.

> [image]

Comment: Our data don’t support that: the difference between up and down votes for questions is not different than on other days.

Comment: Not sure if downvotes are a fitting indicator for that. How about close votes? Unanswered? Less read?

Comment: Admit it - you simply wanted to use the pic... (Which was worth an upvote)

Comment: Medical professionals often say something similar about a full moon. The statistics do not agree, but the myth continues.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>***Based on***</sub>

[image: change career]

[image: carry wp]

[image: carry se]

<sup>*sorry for the [low-res](https://stackapps.com/questions/1508/is-there-a-stack-exchange-icon-available) logos* :P</sup>

Comment: Awesome, nice work Brasofilo! whenever I'm about to give up I'll come back here, re-motivate and soldier on! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's sundayy<sup>y</sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

> [image: woops]

Comment: Pity... I wanted this effect: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198531